# App Clip Push Notification's Authorization Status on Testflight is NotDetermined

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, apple-appclips

When I run on debug mode, the notification's `authorizationStatus` is `Ephemeral` but when I download from Testflight, it's `NotDetermined`

Does push notification work on Testflight for app clip? I was expecting it to be Ephemeral by default because it says that app clip allows push notification by default for 8hrs with Ephemeral status.

Is there something wrong with my configuration?

[image: From Debug]
[image: From Testflight]

Answer (score 0):

This is still the case in 2022, however there is a work around to enable this. So the way the app clip get the `authorizationStatus` `Ephemeral` is through the [App clip card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMfY6.png).
You can enable this with Local Experience

1. Just install the app clip from testflight.
2. Set a [Local Experience](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/app_clips/testing_the_launch_experience_of_your_app_clip)
3. Scan an overwritten QR code with the camera app.
4. Open the app clip with app clip card.
5. Observe, `authorizationStatus` is `Ephemeral`, you should be good to
   test notifications